# Update query not working in qt 5.12.9 using SQLITE DB (querying in for loop)

Tags: sqlite, qt

I am a beginner at sqlite and DB so excuse me if this is a dumb question but I am tired of thinking I don't know if I am doing something foolish here or whatever.

I have created a widget application with a (label-lineEdit) form for name, family (my table columns which its name is user) I put the name and family I press the ok button and everything is fine. After that I realized that if I delete a row, my (id)s won't get in a incremental sequence (like increasing by one) automatically and this was so ugly, so I had to do something. I added a new button (named fix table id), this button while make (row id = record index +1) so this is the code (other things like connecting to DB, Drivers and other stuff work perfect, not any error, so I didn't put them here) but if you need them tell please:

```
void MainWindow::on_fix_table_id_clicked()
{
    QSqlQuery q;
        q.exec("SELECT * FROM user");
        QSqlQueryModel *qm = new QSqlQueryModel();
        qm->setQuery(q);
        int rows = get_rows()-1;
        QSqlRecord qr;
        QSqlQuery s;
       for(int i = 0 ; i <= rows ; i++){
            qr = qm->record(i);
            QString num = QString::number(i+1);
            s.exec("UPDATE user SET id = '"+num+"' WHERE id = '"+qr.value(0).toInt()+"'");
            qDebug() << "UPDATE user SET id = '"+num+"' WHERE id = '"+qr.value(0).toString()+"'";
       }  
}
```

get_rows() method simply uses

```
"SELECT count(1) FROM user"
```

query and works fine
and this is the output (qDebug()) :

```
"UPDATE user SET id = '1' WHERE id = '3'"
"UPDATE user SET id = '2' WHERE id = '4'"
"UPDATE user SET id = '3' WHERE id = '5'"
"UPDATE user SET id = '4' WHERE id = '6'"
"UPDATE user SET id = '5' WHERE id = '7'"
"UPDATE user SET id = '6' WHERE id = '10'"
```

but nothing works nothing updates even in DB Browser and I don't have any issue or error message

I tested this queries in DB Browser for SQLITE and they work perfectly.

Please excuse me for my terrible English and if this question is low-level or something like that:)

Comment: Auto increment ids are not row numbers and should not be treated as such. So don't do updates. If you want row numbers then use ROW_NUMBER() window function: `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM user`

Comment: excuse me if i dont undrestand, when i created my table i saved id as INT(educator did in a video tutrial), so u mean i cant use an int(like i in for loop) for updating them?

Comment: My comment is about SQLite and SQL in general. I suggest that you should not update the table to fill the gaps between the ids.

Comment: tnx, i think now i realized what u meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should organize your table with these 2 columns:

- id (Integer - Unique - Autoincrement) // you will never modify, it's the id of the row.
- entryNumber(Integer) // you can do what you want on this value

When you INSERT INTO, your table id will automatically be unique, and entryNumber can be equal to MAX(entryNumber) + 1

After deleting a row, you will update your table with :

```
UPDATE user SET entryNumber = (entryNumber - 1) WHERE id > xx
```

With xx = your cancelled row id